# How do you add a Validation rule for a pick list Value?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, force.com

I have a two dependent pick list.

System Size
 - 50L S.U.B.
 - 100L S.U.B.
 - 250L S.U.B.
 - 500L S.U.B.
 - 1000L S.U.B.
 - 2000L S.U.B.

Cable Management Tree
 - Right Side
 - Left Side
 - No Cable Management Tree Needed

If I select 2000L SUB from System Size I want to hide ( or Deactivate) Right and Left Side values from Cable management pick list.  I only want to select No Cable Management Tree Needed, when System size is 2000L SUB. Does anybody have any idea, how to put a Validation rule or something that work for my problem. Thanks.

VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Product_Brief__c" extensions="test1">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection  collapsible="false" columns="2">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.System_Size_SUB_2013__c}" required="true"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Cable_Management_Tree__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
         </apex:pageBlock >
     </apex:form >
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a "dependent picklist". You can go into the configuration for the Product_Brief__c object, click on Field Dependencies, and create a new dependency between the two fields. See the [Help & Training](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_defining_field_dependencies.htm&language=en_US) link in your org for more details on how dependent picklists work.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. but in sales force i think we only be able add one Dependency rule right. It already use for something else  in this one. is there any other way.